# error 1329 (02000): no data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error in the following code below. The error is #1329 - No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed. What exactly does this mean and what is it that i am doing incorrectly? Thanks

```
create or replace procedure grade()
begin
declare no,s1,s2,s3,cnt,i,per int(20);
declare c1 cursor for select roll,sub1,sub2,sub3 from student;
set i=0;
select count(*) into cnt from student;
open c1;
while i<=cnt do
fetch c1 into no,s1,s2,s3;
set per=s1+s2+s3/3;
if per>=90 then
update student set grade='A+' where roll=no; 
elseif (per<90 and per>=80)then
update student set grade='A' where roll=no; 
elseif (per<80 and per>=70)then
update student set grade='B+' where roll=no; 
elseif (per<70 and per>=60)then
update student set grade='B' where roll=no; 
elseif (per<60 and per>=50)then
update student set grade='C+' where roll=no; 
elseif (per<50 and per>=40)then
update student set grade='C' where roll=no; 
else 
update student set grade='FAIL' where roll=no; 
end if;
set i=i+1;
end while;
close c1; 
end$$
```

Comment: Does student contain anything?

Comment: 4 columns roll,sub1, sub2, sub3 with 10 rows of records

Comment: Your updating the entire student table every loop, are you not. Why not just write a single update statement. Also you don't need the leading condition in your elsifs. For example if something isn't >= 90 then it is already < 90. This looks like non logical code. Never the less Why have 7 update statements, store the grade in a variable and have a single one outside the if statement, or better yet use a case statement and get rid of the whole if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic:

```
set i = 0;
select count(*) into cnt from student;
while i <= cnt do
```

is going through the loop 1 extra time.  It is on the last trip through the loop that you are getting the error.

If cnt is 3, for instance, then the loops are:

```
0
1
2
3
```

You either want:

```
set i = 1
```

or alternatively

```
while i < cnt
```

In SQL, I would use the first method, because things usually start counting at 1 rather than 0 in SQL -- but they are equivalent.